# How to properly expand <cword> inside an execute command in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to use vim's `:exe` command to `vimgrep` the word under cursor, but I am having problems with the command construction:

If my command is

```
:execute "vimgrep " shellescape(expand("<cword>")) " somedir"
```

it expands to

```
execute "vimgrep 'foo' somedir"
```

But if my command is

```
execute "vimgrep " .. shellescape(expand("<cword>")) .. " somedir"
```

it expands to

```
execute "vimgrep '' somedir"
```

How do I correctly expand `<cword>` raw, without single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping something in single quotes is the main purpose of `shellescape()`. If you don't want those quotes, don't use `shellescape()`.

`:help shellescape()` is used for preparing commands before they are shelled out. Since `:help vimgrep` is an internal tool and nothing is sent to a shell, there is no need for quoting.

This means that the following command should cover most of your needs:

```
:execute "vimgrep " .. expand("<cword>") .. " somedir"
```

Also, `:vimgrep` searches in *files*, not directories. Your command should then look more like:

```
:execute "vimgrep " .. expand("<cword>") .. " somedir/*"
```